# Where to look for image caching

Tags: apache, browser-cache

I am trying to update a web site. There are new images which are uploaded to it. The web server is Apache. The web pages are written in PHP.

But I noticed that the new images are not being loaded when the site's URL is accessed from my Windows 10 computer (and also from my Android phone). Instead, the old images are accessed, but not always. Even if I rename the images on the web server the old ones are loaded.

Even if I create a new web page which accesses one of the new jpgs, the old ones are loaded. (Like, say, mywebpage.php and mywebpage-x.php).

So mywebpage-x.php should try to load image5001.jpg but instead loads image500.jpg from mywebpage.php.

Where would I look for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt that is actually what is happening. If the image url, the link inside the `<img src="...">` tag changes, then certainly no old image is loaded from some cache as a replacement. Most likely you are still loading the old page instead of the new one. Go and check yourself in your browser's development console in the networking tab. There you can see for each request where it is loaded from, cache or server.

Comment: I think what I may have to do is rename the image files.

Comment: In your question you claimed that you already used new names, but still the old images were loaded...